# ionic clickable item icons

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have built a list card with 2 icons in each row. How can I make the icons clickable without loosing the layout of the list? I tried to give the icon element a ng-click, but it doesn't work. And if I surround them with a div I'm loosing the layout of the list.

```
<div class="list card">
  <div ng-repeat="destination in destinations | isActive">
    <div class="item item-divider">
      <span>{{title}}</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right item-balanced">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-home"></i>
      <div>
        <div>{{text1}}</div>
        <div><b>{{text2}}</b></div>
        <div>{{text3()}}</div>
        <div>{{text4()}}</div>
      </div>
      <i class="icon ion-ios-filing"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to keep this layout with the two icons left and right:

[image: layout]

Comment: of course it also changes the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ionic 3

```
<ion-card class="border-top" (click)="eventDetail(event.id)">
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title>
            {{ event.title }} <ion-badge color="primary"> {{ event.date | date : "MMMM d, yyyy - HH:mm"}}</ion-badge>
          </ion-card-title>
          <p>
            {{ event.description }}
          </p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
```

where eventDetail is a function in the respective class and eventId is the value you want to pass.

Answer (score 2):

Turn your `link` tag into a `div` tag, and your `i` tag should be a link tag. Add a little css for the icon. Good to go.

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/7g1wmh6r/))

HTML

```
<div class="list card">
    <div ng-repeat="destination in destinations | isActive">
        <div class="item item-divider">
            <span>{{title}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right item-balanced">
            <a href="#" class="icon ion-ios-home"></a>
            <div>
                <div>{{text1}}</div>
                <div><b>{{text2}}</b>
                </div>
                <div>{{text3()}}</div>
                <div>{{text4()}}</div>
            </div>
            <a href="" class="icon ion-ios-filing"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icon {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: If I do it like you suggested I get the two buttons on top and button and not left and right

Comment: I didn't do any changes on the css in this example.